# Need to output multiple user-in-putted values from a large CSV to a new CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

Sorry for the awkward question but I'm having no luck finding a similar example that I can start with before coming here for tweaks/debugging. Is there some specific name for what I'm wanting to do? If I describe what I'm trying to do, can someone tell me what kind of thing of I should be searching for?

I'm trying to write a simple utility in Python that will open a large "database" CSV (3000 rows, each with 30+ columns) and ask the user for some input, either a row number or if they don't know that, a value from column 1. It will then print out all the rows that match it. The user can then enter the row number they desire and repeat until they have all the rows they want, then output to a CSV which will then be converted to JSON format (this part is at least straightforward).

Can someone point me to an example or supply me with the correct terminology for learning this kind of search and output?

The opening of the CSV file and the change from CSV to JSON at the end have examples I can work from.

Thanks!

Comment: Well SO is not a free code writing service. Python has facilities for operation on `csv` and ``json`` data, and if your dataset is really that small (less than 1GB) you can just search for values, so nothing fancy is needed. If you have any specific problem please include it in your question or add another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something a bit like this:

```
data = [...] # From csv
# Create a dict, with the first column as the key and the row as the value
first_to_row = {cell[0]: cell for cell in data}
result = []

while True:
    inp = raw_input(...)
    selection = None

    # branch based on input
    if # done
        break
    elif # row number
        row_number = ...
        selection = data[row_number]
    else # first column
        first_column = ...
        selection = first_to_row[first_column]

    result.append(selection)
```

You might want to wrap the `data[...]` and `first_to_row[...]` in a `try...catch IndexError` block.

Comment: Thanks! Dictionary! This is just the kind of thing I needed. Thanks for the help!